# how can i pass the constant value made by the keyword #define to a method as a parameter?

Tags: iphone, ios, parameters, constants

I have defined a constant in my some file and added in file where i wanna use it as shown below.

```
#define myMapID 1
```

But the problem is when i passed the value to a method as a parameter, the compiler gives warning, and yes it must do but how can i avoid warnings ?

```
-(void) methodName :(int) mapId
{
//printID
}

[self methodName :myMapID];
```

Comment: what warning do you get?

Comment: by using #define i guess the datatype is not clear to the compiler or don't know what, so it gives the warning that it should be according to the method's parameter to i am passing it to. In compilers language the warning is like "myTestAppDelegate' may not respond to '-methodName : mapID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd that it would give you a warning on that. try:

```
#define myMapID (int) 1
```

maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a (global) static/constant int, much clearer than #define and won't give a warning.

Comment: // Prefs.h
//extern NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT;
//
// Prefs.m
//NSString * const PREFS_MY_CONSTANT = @"prefs_my_constant"; 
if this is what you are trying to say ?  if yes then in my case i am defining all the constants a single time and using them in many files so this thing would be perfect for my case.